# How does a traditional third-party library play with the `module`?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules, c++23

CMake already supports the most basic use of `module`, which is good, but the `module` itself doesn't seem to be ready, or rather the large number of libraries consisting of `header files + source files` is not ready.

Here is a minimal example for `MSVC`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.26")
    # 3.25
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "3c375311-a3c9-4396-a187-3227ef642046")
elseif (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.27")
    # 3.26
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "See `https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v${CMAKE_VERSION}/Help/dev/experimental.rst`.")
endif (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.26")
# turn on the dynamic depends for ninja
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP ON)

project(test)

set(TEMP_CXX_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp_module)
if (NOT DEFINED ENV{VCToolsInstallDir})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find path to VC Tools in environment variables!")
endif (NOT DEFINED ENV{VCToolsInstallDir})

if (NOT EXISTS $ENV{VCToolsInstallDir})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid VC Tools installation path!")
else ()
    message(STATUS "Found VC Tools in: [$ENV{VCToolsInstallDir}]")
endif (NOT EXISTS $ENV{VCToolsInstallDir})

if (NOT EXISTS $ENV{VCToolsInstallDir}modules/std.ixx)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find std.ixx! Please check MSVC version(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION})!")
else()
    message(STATUS "Found module std.ixx in: [$ENV{VCToolsInstallDir}modules\\std.ixx]")
endif (NOT EXISTS $ENV{VCToolsInstallDir}modules/std.ixx)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_compile_features(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        cxx_std_23
)

set_target_properties(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

configure_file(
        $ENV{VCToolsInstallDir}modules/std.ixx
        ${TEMP_CXX_MODULE_PATH}/std.ixx
        COPYONLY
)

target_compile_options(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        /Wv:18
)

target_sources(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        FILE_SET module_files
        TYPE CXX_MODULES
        BASE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        FILES

        ${TEMP_CXX_MODULE_PATH}/std.ixx

        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/m1.ixx
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/m2.ixx
)

target_sources(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        FILE_SET header_files
        TYPE HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        FILES

        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_header.hpp
)
```

File `test_header.hpp`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

namespace test {
    template<typename T>
    concept no_matter_what_is = std::move_constructible<T>;
}
```

File `m1.ixx`:

```cpp
module;

#include <src/test_header.hpp>

export module m1;

export namespace test_m1 {
    // Additionally, when a module-import-declaration in a module unit of some module M imports another module unit U of M,
    // it also imports all translation units imported by non-exported module-import-declarations in the module unit purview of U.
    template<test::no_matter_what_is T>
    class M1 {};

//  template<typename T>
//  class M1_OK {};
//  template<typename T>
//  using M1 = M1_OK<T>;
}// namespace test_m1
```

File `m2.ixx`:

```cpp
export module m2;

import m1;
// for `std::move_constructible`
import std;

export namespace test_m2 {
    // Error: error C7570: 'std::move_constructible': variable template has already been defined
    template<std::move_constructible T>
    class M2 : public test_m1::M1<T> {
    };
}// namespace test_m2
```

File `main.cpp`:

```cpp
import std;
import m1;
import m2;

int main() {

test_m1::M1<int> m1{};
    test_m2::M2<int> m2{};

return 0;
}
```

`Output`:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32323\include\concepts(116): error C7570: 'std::move_constructible': variable template has already been defined
```

The redefinition may be caused by a conflict between `#include <concepts>` in `test_header.hpp` and  in `import std;`, but I pessimistically think that this form of implicit export (I mean `std::move_constructible` been exported due to the `test_m1::M1` in module `m1`) is inevitable, which means that to use the `module`, all `unready` third-party libraries must be discarded.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082040/16591884

Comment: I can't speak to your situation because I can't get `import std;` to work. However with 17.5 I have noticed that however you include/import something you need to be consistant about it. That said you may be able to get away with using `import <concepts>;` or the flags that does that for you automagically

Comment: It's not about using `import <concepts>`, I mean, there are countless third-party libraries here, and you want to use them, but once you `include` their files, you will face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the header inclusion guards inside "concepts" file not being triggered when including it in the global module fragment, because the `import <concepts>` does not perform any inclusion guard checking.
I must double on the suggestion by @Mgetz - take any dependencies and compile them to header units and then import those header units instead.

Module migration is meant to be bottom-up.